# Very weird linuxbrew installation issue

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, homebrew

I am installing linuxbrew in a linux machine. I typed

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
in the console. However it says

```
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/install -d -o user1 -g user1 -m 0755 /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew
/usr/bin/install: cannot create directory ‘/home/linuxbrew’: Permission denied
Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/install -d -o user1 -g user1 -m 0755 /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew
```

That's weird. Because I can create a directory under /home just by typing `mkdir /home/linuxbrew` and it did create that dir. And I also have sudo permission. I don't understand what caused such error.

This is what `uname -a` output:`Linux workstation 4.18.0-26-generic #27-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 2 15:36:16 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Oh, and I found when I type sudo mkdir /home/linuxhomebrew, I got permission denied. I don't understand why a normal user can add a directory while root can not.